# ActiveRecord query methods response - need to demistify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Intro: Rails 3.2; 'a' is an object, and ActiveRecord model, which has_many messages (also ActiveRecord models) - though that's probably not very important for my question.

So here's the question: why this,

- `irb(main):046:0> a.messages.respond_to?(:where)
  => true`

but then also this,

- `irb(main):047:0> a.messages.methods.include?(:where)
  => false`

?

What's happening? Obviously some Ruby magic here, which makes these tho ways of exploring the object yield different result; one is querying the Array class, I guess, and the other is querying... that *thing* which responds to :where (among other methods). Don't even know what to call it. My guess is it's querying the object of Array class with some stuff... 'mixed in'? (think I heard that term used in Ruby context a lot...)

Comment: Which version of Rails?

Comment: Ah, sorry - didn't think of that; 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit here is likely `method_missing`.

Lots of the "magical" aspects of Ruby and Rails are due to this nifty little method. Basically, as a last-ditch effort before throwing a NoMethodError, Ruby calls a method called `method_missing` on its objects. This allows Rails (pre-4.0) to respond to dynamic finders like `find_by_name_and_email`. It would be ludicrous to define all possible combinations of columns across all models, so Rails overloads `method_missing` and constructs the relevant SQL query there.

Additionally, when you're going to respond to a method call using `method_missing`, you can override Ruby's `respond_to?` method.

Here's an example:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    if meth == :bar
      puts 'yep!'
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(meth)
    if meth == :bar
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.methods.include?(:bar)
# => false
foo.respond_to?(:bar)
# => true
```

Comment: hm, ok.. I know about method_missing and how it's used to enable all the dynamic finders stuff -- but those are class method of a model class, if I get it right. Here, however, we get back an Array of such models; and that Array instance is where the querying "helpers"  are supported; all these 'where' and 'paginate' and 'order' and what else is there. If I get it right (I may very well be mistaken), they are not instance, nor class methods of my model. I suppose this must be something like Django's QuerySet API. Need to dig deeper into RoR  docs now...

Comment: Rails uses something called an AssociationProxy behind the scenes to enable this behavior. It's a little more explicit in Rails 4 -- for example, in my app, `User.first.assignments.class` returns ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Assignment. AssociationProxies are where all of those finder methods and such live.